# "build.android.buildType" is not allowed

Tags: android, react-native, build, expo, eas

Firstly, english is not my native language sorry for that.
i'm developing react native project on expo.I need to build project.Eas working on expo.I writed `Eas build:configure` and create eas.json.

eas.json :

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 5.9.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {},
    "android": {
      "buildType": "apk"
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

and after, im writing `eas build --platform android --profile android` but I get output like this:

**eas.json is not valid.**

**"build.android.buildType" is not allowed**

Where am I making mistakes?

Answer (score 1):

within your "build", you need to add "android":{"buildType":"apk"} inside the "production". You've added outside "production"